# Why does Python 'hold' files that have been written to file open so that they can't be deleted?

Tags: python, file

When I write a file using Python from within a class (using iPython and the Spyder ID) I've noticed that I can't delete these files for a while afterward because they are apparently still in use, even though the program that produced the file has finished running. My question is: does anybody know how to prevent this behavior as I would like to continually produce and delete files at will whilst testing my programs (instead of enumerating file names).

## -----------------edit: Answers to questions------------------

1) I am using Windows 7

2) By 'program has finished' I mean the program was executed using F5 but the iPython console remains open.

3) I have also observed this behavior when using a `with` block. Whenever writing files, I only ever use a `with` statement

Comment: When you say "the program that produced the file has finished running", do you mean you closed iPython entirely? If not, the program is still running. Also, are you closing the files properly, by opening them with a `with` statement?

Comment: What OS is this happening on?

Comment: @user2357112  So your saying that a (say) a HelloWorld.py program (for example) remains running, even after you press F5?

Comment: @user3059024: The program here is the Python process, not HelloWorld.py.

Comment: Is there a way to terminate the Python process without closing and reopening an iPython console?

Comment: Nope. Not possible.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info